# Controlling DirectVobSub filter programmatically

Tags: video, visual-c++, directshow, subtitle

I have a DirectShow-based player, that uses DirectVobSub to show subtitles.

I want to have shortcuts to move the subtitles sync up and down.

This is possible in the VobSub dialogue, but no shortcuts.

I use Visual C++, and I am at the point where I have IBaseFilter pointer to the VobSub filter, and I guess I have to somehow invoke that interface. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get `IDirectVobSub` and alike interfaces using regular `IUnknown::QueryInterface` from `IBaseFilter`.

To get the definition of these interfaces you, generally, need to check the source used to build the filter in first place (you got it from somewhere, right?). Although a copy from another repo should work out too.

https://github.com/Fluffiest/mpc-hc/blob/cfd18b62248c0e97f5626d94539d60d5361cc5a1/src/filters/transform/VSFilter/IDirectVobSub.h#L30

```
    interface __declspec(uuid("EBE1FB08-3957-47ca-AF13-5827E5442E56"))
IDirectVobSub :
    public IUnknown
    {
        STDMETHOD(get_FileName) (THIS_
                                 WCHAR* fn  // fn should point to a buffer allocated to at least the length of MAX_PATH (=260)
                                ) PURE;

        STDMETHOD(put_FileName) (THIS_
                                 WCHAR* fn
                                ) PURE;
```

Comment: Clear and pithy (and working too...), thanks a lot!

Comment: As a complementary question, how do I create a new IDirectVobSub object? I mean, if the video has no subtitle, and therefore DirectVobSub is not loaded, and I want to add a subtitle file to the video, how do I do that? So far I've tried `CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(IDirectVobSub), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IBaseFilter),(void**)&pFilter);` but I get "class is not registered" error

Comment: The first argument should be this CLSID: [`{93A22E7A-5091-45ef-BA61-6DA26156A5D0}`](https://github.com/Fluffiest/mpc-hc/blob/cfd18b62248c0e97f5626d94539d60d5361cc5a1/src/filters/transform/VSFilter/DirectVobSubFilter.h#L41)

Comment: OK. Now everything return S_OK, I call `IGraphBuilder::AddFilter`, and `pFilter->QueryInterface`, I even enumed the filters to confirm it's there (it is), yet... the actual filter is a no show.